# Type '(oldPlacePhotos: string[]) => string[]' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 28 more

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Cannot figure this one out for the life of me.

Here is the code example

**Parent.tsx**

```
  const [placePhotos, setPlacePhotos] = useState<string[]>([])

  ...
  useEffect(() => foo(setPlacePhotos), [])
```

**helper.ts where** `foo()` **exists**

```
type GooglePlaceInfoObject = {
  setPlacePhotos?: (photos: Array<string>) => string[]
}

foo({ setPlacePhotos }: GooglePlaceInfoObject) {
        if (setPlacePhotos) {
          // this returns an array of strings
          const photosArray = googlePlaceDetailsObject.photos.map(photo => {
            return photo.getUrl({
              maxWidth: 320,
              maxHeight: 426,
            })
          })
          // error happens here!
          setPlacePhotos((oldPlacePhotos: string[]) => [
            ...oldPlacePhotos,
            ...photosArray,
          ])
        }
}
```

**Error when using** `setPlacePhotos`

```
Argument of type '(oldPlacePhotos: string[]) => string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.
  Type '(oldPlacePhotos: string[]) => string[]' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 28 more.
```

how do you fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom `GooglePlaceInfoObject` type unnecessarily restricts the type of `setPlacePhotos` so that it does not support the [functional form of setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). To fix this, you can change it to something like:

```
type GooglePlaceInfoObject = {
  setPlacePhotos?: (photos: string[] | ((oldPhotos: string[]) => string[])) => void
}
```